# Codeigniter Sessions Third Variable Gets Lost

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to save checkbox data using PHP sessions in CodeIgniter.

After submitting the form the data is saved in the session variables and can be called upon on the next page.

The problem is however that when I then continue to another page the last session variable is empty when called upon, while the first two are still available.

I also tried using the standard PHP `$_SESSION` which gives me the exact same result.

The processing file contains:

```
$price_low = $this->input->post('price_low');
$price_high = $this->input->post('price_high');
$stock_only = $this->input->post('stock_only');
$session = array('price_low' => $price_low, 'price_high' => $price_high, 'stock_only' => $stock_only);
$this->session->set_userdata($session);`
```

Retrieving the data:

```
$this->session->userdata('price_low');
$this->session->userdata('price_high');
$this->session->userdata('stock_only');
```

Comment: Paste your code please

Comment: Tip when asking question formatting code https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Check what you getting when you `print_r($session); exit(); ` before you set `$this->session->set_userdata($session);` ?

Comment: That results in my script terminating execution halfway.